# Wordpress Contact Form 7 missing form name

Tags: wordpress, forms

I'm using WordPress 4.2.2 and Contact Form 7 version 4.2.1. But when my contact form shortcode outputs the html code the name="" attribute is blank and W3C html validator is giving me errors because of this. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "**Contact** form 7", but I guess that is beside the point.

You can set the form name attribute using the `html_name` attribute of the shorttag like this:

```
[contact-form-7 id="7" title="My awesome contact form" html_name="my_awesome_contact_form"]
```

It actually seems a bit strange that this is empty by default since that is considered invalid markup - so you may want to contact the developer(s) and let him / them know, so it can be fixed - I can't even find any documentation referencing the `html_name` attribute - I only found it by looking directly in the source...

Comment: I've opened a thread regarding this in the [support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/bug-form-name-attribute-is-empty-by-default?replies=1#post-7160410)

Comment: Sorry about the misnaming. I've been up for 48 hours coding in order to meet a deadline and then this happens. But your answer does fix my issue. But the plugin still should not output a blank attribute. So I did post something to the plugin author yesterday before I posted on here. Thanks for your help.